# Using "merge" and "include"

Tags: android-layout, android

I'm trying to put a copyright image in the bottom of my `LinearLayout` with an "include tag". I am doing it successfully, but when I'm trying to add `android:layout_marginTop="330dp"` or `android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"` for instance to my include - it doesn't show in the UI.
What is the problem ?

Here is my code:
copyrights.xml:

```
 <merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/copyrights"
            android:id="@+id/copyrights"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"/>
</merge>
```

mylayout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">  
        <include layout="@layout/copyrights"  android:layout_marginTop="330dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try to add margins in Imageview(merger) itself and check if it works?

Comment: it does, but that's the whole point. If I'll add it over there, I'll have incompatibility between screen resolutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<include />` tag is basically a copy&paste instruction for the android layout framework. It's not an actual object in your layout hierachy. That means that it can't have margin/padding/size/any other layout property.

Assign the margin to the `<ImageView />` in your layout instead.

Comment: And why does "android:layout_marginBottom" doesn't work in any situation ?

Comment: Can you explain that a bit more and add a few details? I've seen that work, so "any situation" is a bit of an overstatement. :)

Comment: I'm trying to do that:

<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView
   android:src="@drawable/copyrights"
         android:id="@+id/copyrights"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"  />
</merge>

and my image still shows on top of the layout instead a few inches from the bottom.

Comment: Oh that just tells the ImageView that it has to have 5dp empty space below it. Since your LinearLayout adds new views on the top by default you won't see much of that *(you will only see empty space between views if you add another component)*. You can change where the LinearLayout adds new views by adding e.g. `android:gravity="bottom"` to it. That means all new views get placed on the bottom, which should result in what you intent to achieve.

Comment: and if I want some views on top and only one image at the bottom ?

Comment: I'd say in this case LinearLayout isn't the best choice. Rather use a RelativeLayout and add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to the ImageView. For the other views, align the first one the same way to the top and the others relative to the first top view. You can also nest layouts, align a LinearLayout to the top of the RelativeLayout and add children like you are doing now.